# Query by snimpy's Session takes too much time

Tags: python, snmp, snimpy

I use `snimpy` library to get query by `OID`.

This query execution time takes about **~15sec**'s:

```
from snimpy.snmp import Session

s = Session(host, "83L80N3")
oid, host_cpu = s.get((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 9, 109, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1))[0]
```

but system `snmpget` executes immediately.

#### Question

Did i missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Set "localhost" explicitly.

```
s = Session("localhost", "83L80N3")
```